# Check all array values are diffrent

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, random

so i have 4 arraylist values and i want to see that they all diffrents so there will not be an duplicate value(all values are strings)
Here is my code hope you can help me with that i am kind of confusse i tried look up for that i began to mased up with to many if conditions for each value.

```
    List<String>Answers=new ArrayList<String>();//מערך תשובות
    Answers.add(f.getName().toString());//הוספת התשובה הנכונה
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    //if(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString()!= f.getName().toString())
    //{
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());//הוספת 3 תשובות רנדומליות
    num = r.nextInt(30);
//  }
//  else
//      num = r.nextInt(30);        
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
```

Comment: use Set if you want unique elements.

Comment: Using Hashset should help you.. Refer http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/hashset/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the List already `contains` your value:

```
String valToAdd = db.getFlag(num).getName().toString();
if(!Answers.contains(valToAdd)){
    Answers.add(valToAdd);
}
```

Also, from your comments, I see you try to compare Strings with == or !=.

Always use `string1.equals(string2)` for comparement for Strings, as they are objects, and not primitive datatypes.

Comment: Lol ion my test ive been losing ten points on equels hh

Comment: Then your teacher should read into Java programming again.

Comment: No it was my fault i always forgot this hhh used your solutions works great i puted that in for and its works :) tank you

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want duplicates then opt of [Set Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
Set<String> namesSet=new HashSet<>();
namesSet.add("ABC");
namesSet.add("DEF");
namesSet.add("ABC"); // this will not be added because Set doesn't allow any duplicates
```

Note : `Set#add()` method returns boolean indicating that whether or not element added successfully

Comment: ok i will use it but if its duplicate and i need 4 asnwers so one is out i need to do it in while condition ?

Comment: `while(Answers.size() < 4){//Add new answer}` would be a possible while condition

Comment: @adids1221 , yes you can do it that way , if taking input from users so take untill size of set is `4` and you get all your unique options !!

Answer (score 1):

```
Use HashSet instead of ArrayList. Hash set ensures that you dont have duplicate values. Just use in the same way as you are implementing ArrayList. 
e.g.
    HashSet<String> answers=new HashSet<String>();  
    answers.add(f.getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);

    answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);

    answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
```